# Uncertain Error Occurs in Symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am doing my project in symfony.

Sometimes when my pages load i got below error :

> Fatal error:  Class
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy
>   contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::close,
>   SessionHandlerInterface::gc) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\meopin_mobile2\trunk\var\cache\prod\classes.php on
>   line 348

Do anybody have any idea about this error , how can i stop this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the caches with a command `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod`